# gzclient throwing Ogre::InvalidParametersException

Tags: ogre

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all. I am attempting to build Gazebo from source this weekend. I was able to get everything built however when I attempt to run the gzclient I get an exception. Could this possible be due to my building of OGRE manually? I couldn't use the default OGRE as it was missing a Cg plugin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additional info
I am running Ubuntu.
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

Here is the output for gzclient. gzserver was already running with the empty world.
user@Azul:~$ gzclient
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InvalidParametersException'
what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): All framebuffer formats with this texture internal format unsupported in GLFrameBufferObject::initialise at /home/jkoberstein/tmp/ogre_src_v1-7-4/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLFrameBufferObject.cpp (line 276)
Aborted (core dumped)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29/gzclient-throwing-ogre::invalidparametersexception/) by [Kazaud](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34/kazaud/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So I figured this one out on my own. Turns out that all I needed to do was to upgrade my graphics driver. You need the latest drivers to support the configuration used by Gazebo. I was using NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version 173) and I switched to NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version current)[Recommended]

---

Originally posted by [Kazaud](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34/kazaud/) with karma: 36 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2